# How to make a mobile designed site appear similar on differn't screen resoloutions

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-size

I am currently designing a mobile site, that would work perfectly on a 320x480 screen. The issue comes, as newer phones don't use that size anymore, and are much much bigger. (As I found out after I put all that effort in and read it on my phone.) I was wondering if there is any easy way to make it all expand the the proper size I would like it to look without going ahead and giving everything a view-width/vw or view-height/vh rating. (Nvm, I wonder how that would impact the font size.)

Or would I need to go ahead and do that, or something similar? (As it would be particularly bad if it wasn't mobile friendly, for a variety of reasons involving it's creation.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will get downvoted because your question is quite vague. What you are looking for is called responsive web design. There's plenty of info if you google it. After you have read about that, you can come back here and post your code if you have problems with it. If you do that please also consider reading [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Responsive_design) might help, that is the reason we use responsive design as a solution to the different screen sizes. The following is added to the `<head>` so that the browser will respond to the pixel/screen size.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also [media queires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are used to change the design based on the screen width, em is used instead of px as px is absolute where as em will respond according to the device, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size). Percentages are used instead of absolute sizes (where necessary) you can read more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/percentage).

Answer (score 0):

Using media queries, you should saw something like

```
@media(max-width:768px){.someClass{someCssStiling:xValue;}}
```

This means that this styles will work only under 768px.
You can read the documentation about media queries here (and in many other places, there's a lot of doc. on internet):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Hope it help!